# PHP + mySQL - Match exact word

Tags: php, mysql, regex, cpu-word, match

I have some texts in a mysql database and I'm using this query to try to match an exact word in a query with php:

```
$palavra = "aquecimento";

$query = "SELECT * FROM webqda_fontesInt_text WHERE plainText REGEXP '[[:<:]]" . $palavra . "[[:>:]]' AND projectoId='$projectoId' AND reciclagem='0' AND id='$id' GROUP BY id";
```

Can someone please explain me why this returns records like: "aquecimento", "aquecimentos", "desaquecimentos"?

I only wanted to return the exact match, but it's not working like it should.

Thank you in advance!

---

**More Information**

Also I can have words like ""aquecimento." that I want to return or "aquecimento!"

Comment: If you want an exact match, you shouldn't be using regexp in the first place. Use like, which is faster, and add a white-space character at the end of the word to avoid plural.

Answer (score 2):

**Final Update**

Ok, I was able to take a look and run some tests. Eventually got this to work:

```
WHERE plainText RLIKE '[ ]".$palavra."[?!.,]?[ ]'
```

Just add more punctuations inside of the [ ] and be mindful of escaping those items that need escaped.

Let me know of any issues. (I do not know if this is the best way to handle it, but it does work). That said, if anyone has any suggestions let me know and I will modify it accordingly.

---

**Update**

Alright, doing some reading this *should* be what you are looking for:

<del>WHERE plainText REGEXP '\s".$palavra."[!.]{1}\s'</del>

I am not 100% on the regex, and may need tweaking. For the information I used [MySQL Manual for REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). If I get a chance to test / tweak it I will. Best of luck.

---

Old Answer:
Why not just use `LIKE` instead of the regex?

```
WHERE plainText LIKE '% ".$palavra." %'
```

Should do it, just add the spaces before and after the word.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but I'm using regex because it should work :) Also I can have words like ""aquecimento." that I want to return or "aquecimento!" and with LIKE I can's.

Comment: @Alexandre: You should add that to the original post then to avoid answers that you know won't work.

Comment: @Brad F Jacobs: Tried this, but now it doesn't return anything... Thank you for your help. I guess I'm going to do it the wrong way and check what char is after and before the word against an array of chars...

Comment: @Alexandre Mota, did a final update. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
"REGEXP '\s".$palavra."\s'"
```

I don't understand your regexp, so, I'm sorry, but I can't answer why you matching "aquecimentos"

> > Also I can have words like ""aquecimento." that I want to return or "aquecimento!"

REGEXP in this case would've be:

```
REGEXP '\s[\"\\']+".$palavra."(!)?[\"\\']+\s'
```

That means, " and ' is allowed before and after $palavra. It's also ok if ! is RIGHT after palavra.

I did not test it, but I think it will work.

Comment: aquecimento is a portuguese word :D

Comment: I figured :) I can't understand this part: [[:<:]] and why you need this (I can assume, you tried to tell that before and after your word should be whitespace, but whitespaces in regexps is \s)